# In Youtube player, see the frame when it's paused

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api

I'm doing an application that uses youtube API. I select the time with the "seekto" function, but when the video jumps to that time, it appears like the following screenshot:

[image: Paused video]

There's any option to remove all this things (bar, load circle, ...), and only see the frame of the video in that time??

Code:

```
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
     playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 2 },
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: '1WcvD6lu2Yg',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      }
    });
  }
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.pauseVideo();

  }
  function salta(sec) {
      player.seekTo(sec, true);
  }
```

Thank you!

Edited:

Solved, the problem was the parameter "false" of the function seekTo. In "true" position, it loads the following second correctly.

Comment: Post your code implementation so far.

Comment: Edited with the code. The problem is, as I said, when I change the time. When this happens, the Youtube API don't reproduce (or show the frame) on the new point.